# Can we change the placement of Div in mobile or tablet view (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change ordering of a div. What I have is.. (HTML)

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="navgtn-menu"></div>
<div class="search-bar"></div>
```

Now I want search-bar div on  just above nvgtn-menu div in mobile view?
is there any option to do that? or any trick?

Comment: which bootstrap version? Bootstrap 3 does offer some functionality for that (assuming you want a column layout on larger screens)

Answer (score 0):

HEres my suggestion:

**flex-order** with css3:

```
<div class="core">
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="navgtn-menu"></div>
<div class="search-bar"></div>
</div>
```

IN MOBILE MEDIA QUERY::

```
.core {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
 }

.navgtn-menu {
-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;  
-moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;     
-ms-flex-order: 3;     
-webkit-order: 3;  
order: 3;
}

.search-bar {
-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;  
-moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;     
-ms-flex-order: 2;     
-webkit-order: 2;  
order: 2;
}
```

ONly thing is this wont work in IE9 or below so................

if not do **js append** to change the order or duplicate it below it

```
$( $('.search-bar').html() ).appendTo('.mobile-move');
```

Which will look like:

```
    <div class="core">
    <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="mobile-move"></div>
    <div class="navgtn-menu"></div>
    <div class="search-bar"></div>
    </div>
```

This way it will just duplicate but with css media query you can hide/show this.

Answer (score -2):

like this :)

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="search-bar"></div>
<div class="navgtn-menu"></div>
```

Comment: Im pretty sure he means without changing the div order